# MODX Revo, Path Issue with friendly URLS (only in IE)

Tags: internet-explorer, mod-rewrite, modx, friendly-url, base-path

my MODX installation have serval contexts, each context go to an other domain. Friendly URLS is on.
Everything works fine in Mozilla, Chrome and Safari.

Now we find out that the site do not Work in IE (version 11).I discovered that firendly urls creates the alias path twice.

The Base-Tag is in any template:

```
<base href="[[!++site_url]]" />
```

**Example url in firefox/mozilla/safari:** hostname/section/page.

**Example url in IE:** hostname/section/section/page.

Do anybody have an idea how can I fix this problem?

I know. IE11 is outdated since Edge comes out. But there a many user that still uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution is that pages that hold childs should NOT be marked as "container".